# Visual Studio has encounter in RDLC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, extension-methods, rdlc

Well, I'm just little bit curious about this error. This error will comes up once every time i open the project and set the expression for a value and use some extension. But the extension it works properly and in the *design time* i have no problem or crashing encountered from this error. 
I just want to know what is really happened behind this error and why this error comes up, then the extension is working properly?. Thanks advance.

[image]

Comment: it happens also to me, but in the end everthing works fine

Answer (score 2):

Em... May be you should follow a suggestion to start msvc with /log parameter and check the log for error description?